# White background in the program list [LyX]

Tags: lyx

I went to Tools->Settings->Listing and entered the following piece of code:

```
backgroundcolor={\color[gray]{0.9}}
frame=single
mathescape=true
```

Although, for some reason, it keeps a white background (as can be seen in the following image). How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: I don't know, but you might find how to customize it by going to Help > Embedded Objects, and reading Section 8 "Program Code Listings".

Comment: Hi, welcome. I can't reproduce that with the info you've given. If you could do the following, it would likely be easier to debug: make a new document containing only that listing, make sure you have the same settings, so the bad output is reproduced. Then go to View -> Source pane, choose *Complete source* (or something similar) from the drop down menu on the right side of that panel (might say *Current paragraph* by default), copy all the code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, and paste it into your question? You can edit your question, there should be a link just below it.